# How to avoid polygon fill in substance painter painting unselected polygons?

Tags: textures

when using polygon fill in substance painter, it sometimes also paints different polygons that I havn't selected. (See image).

I am using the Polygon Fill on a black mask that is attached to a fill layer.

[image]